# How to use Classes with RestrictedPython

Tags: python

Im trying to learn how to use the `RestrictedPython` module to run a user defined input code.
In this particular case I wish the user could define his own class.
According to documentation the sandbox I'm setting up is this :

```
from RestrictedPython import compile_restricted,safe_globals
from RestrictedPython.Eval import default_guarded_getiter,default_guarded_getitem
from RestrictedPython.Guards import guarded_iter_unpack_sequence,safer_getattr

safe_globals['__metaclass__'] = type
safe_globals['_getiter_'] = default_guarded_getiter
safe_globals['_getitem_'] = default_guarded_getitem
safe_globals['_iter_unpack_sequence_'] = guarded_iter_unpack_sequence
safe_globals['getattr'] = safer_getattr

src="""
def a():
    class b:
        pass

        def test(self):
            return 4

    c = b()

    return c.test()
"""

loc = {}

byte_code = compile_restricted(src, '<inline code>', 'exec')

exec(byte_code, safe_globals, loc)
    
res = loc['a']()

print(res)
```

Unfortunately, this is not correct. In fact I'm obtaining the following trace error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/DATA/PROGETTI/2021/PYTHON_TEST_CASE/main.py", line 30, in <module>
    res = loc['a']()
  File "<inline code>", line 1, in a
  File "<inline code>", line 1, in b
NameError: name '__name__' is not defined
```

If possible I wish to have a solution to this error or a working example with the use of classes.

Answer (score 0):

the solution to the problem is to add a name definition as :

```
safe_globals['__name__'] = 'restricted namespace'
```

for informations this issue was located here :
https://github.com/zopefoundation/RestrictedPython/issues/204

The documentation has been updated with :

```
name__ must be set.
 As classes need a namespace to be defined in.
 It is the name of the module the class is defined in.
 You might set it to an arbitrary string.
```